# Nested arguments RCurl

Tags: r, api, curl

I like to know if someone can help me with this problem. I have a Iungo energy logger and like to extract logged values from its memory. Its producer gave me a curl code but I like to extract it using R because I have no experience with curl. The curl code is:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"seq":1,"method":"datalog_get","arguments":{"t1":"1458663908", "t2":"1458664000", "oid": "538d72d9", "prop":"T1"}}'
http://192.168.178.22/iungo/api_request
```

From what I could find on Stackoverflow I composed a R code:

```
library(RCurl)
data = postForm("http://192.168.178.41/iungo/api_request",
                 .opts = list(seq="1", method="datalog_get",
                 arguments=c(t1="1458169200", t2="1458255600", 
                 oid= "7bbf70c3",   prop="T1")))
```

But all variations I tried resulted in a crash. I suspect the problem is in the nested arguments, any suggestions?
Thanks, Tim.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
library(httr)

res <- POST("http://192.168.178.22/iungo/api_request",
            body=list(seq = 1L,
                      method = "datalog_get", 
                      arguments = list(t1 = "1458663908", 
                                       t2 = "1458664000", 
                                       oid = "538d72d9", 
                                       prop = "T1")))
content(res, as="parsed")
```

Comment: Thank you hrbrmstr for your answer. /t I tried your code but got an "Expectation Failed" in return. Specifically: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head><title>417 - Expectation Failed</title></head>
<body>
  <h1>417 - Expectation Failed</h1>
 </body>
</html>` Do you have an idea what I can try next?

Comment: It's possible I managed to get that request in while cookies were still set. I'll try it again and see what extra headers/cookies/params are needed.